# Partial definition of generic abstract function

Tags: function, scala, generics, member

In scala is it possible to declare a generic abstract function in a base class and then
provide different concrete implementations in various derived classes like this:

```
abstract class B {

    def foo[T,V](u:T):V
}

class D extends B {

    def foo(u:T_0) = {...}
    def foo(u:T_1) = {...}
    ....
}
```

and likewise for classes D1, D2,... derived from B (with possibly different concrete types T_j)
accross classes D_j in order to use obj.foo(u) and the compiler flags whenever foo is used on an argument of a type for which foo is not defined.

In short the question is: is a class derived from B considered concrete as soon as foo is defined
for at least one concrete type T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you can't specialize `U` and `T` within `D`, you have to match the parameters from the base class. You also can't provide individual special cases of an override within a subclass, like a partial function -- a concrete class must provide implementations for each abstract method, covering all parameters.

It seems to me like what you really want is type parameters at the class level, on `B` itself, so that derived classes specialize those parameters and then the interface of the `foo` method they inherit becomes specialized accordingly. So, you'd want to do something like:

```
abstract class B[T, V] {
  def foo(u: T): V
}

class D extends B[String, Int] {
  def foo(u: String): Int = u.length
}
```

(You may also find it useful to add variance annotations `class B[-T, +V]`, but that's another story.)

Comment: OK. Thanks. This is unfortunate.

Comment: Why unfortunate? The whole idea of using the type system in this way is to be able to have rigorous compile-time checks of the validity of your method invocations. Depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, there may be other, more elaborate approaches. There are all sorts of ways to be able to relate the types in `foo`. I think you'll probably have to ask a new, more specific question to get help on that though.